# Ember handlebars-helper renders property-name as string instead of the value

Tags: ember.js

In my template i render out: `<b>{{firstname}}</b>`which resolves into **Mads**

I then use my handlebar-helper `trimString`:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('trimString', function(passedString) {
    var theString = passedString.substring(0,100);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(theString)
});
```

Like `<b>{{trimString firstname}}</b>`, but that ends up rendering **firstname**

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're formatting `firstName` string itself, not controller's property, so probably this should work:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('trimString', function(passedString) {
    var theString = this.get(passedString).substring(0,100);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(theString)
});
```